# Trying to Iterate Through File and Having Issues

Tags: python, list, file

So I have a file "game.txt" which consist of an instruction and a number. The instruction is either "coin," "jump," or "none." "Coin" stores the number following the instruction, "jump" will jump to a new instruction relative to itself and do whatever that instructions says, and "none" will do nothing. However, "jump +2" would continue to the instruction two lines below, and "jump -5" causes the instruction 5 lines above to be executed next.

I want to be able to iterate through the file, write the number on a new file, and count how many "coins" there are at the end. I already have a decent function that gets me somewhat close to this, but I have some bugs that I can't seem to figure out.

ex.)

- I have 533 as my total, but only 528 entries in my new file
- I would also like to simplify the code if possible (looks redundant in some parts)

game.txt file [game.txt file link](https://easyupload.io/axuyxo)

```
def counting_coins(file):
    
    count = 0
    game_list = []  # list of all game steps
    valid_coins = []  # list of all coin values
    try:
        coins = open("coins.txt", "x")
    except FileExistsError:
        coins = open("coins.txt", "w")  # if file already exists
    
    with open(file, "r") as cc:
    ### LOOPS ###
        for line in cc:
            game_list.append(line[0:-1])  # append each line to list to index and iterate

    for i in range(len(game_list)):
        current = game_list[i]  # keep track of current step
        if "coin" == current[0:4]:
            count += 1
            if game_list[i][5:6] == "+":
                valid_coins.append(current[6:] + "\n")
                # count += 1
            elif game_list[i][5:6] == "-":
                valid_coins.append("-" + current[6:] + "\n")
                # count += 1
        elif "jump" == current[0:4]:
            if current[5:6] == "+":
                num = int(current[6:])
                jump = game_list[i + num]
            elif current[5:6] == "-":
                num = int(current[6:])
                num = -num
                jump = game_list[i + num]
            if "coin" == jump[0:4]:
                count += 1
                if jump[5:6] == "+":
                    valid_coins.append(jump[6:] + "\n")
                    # count += 1
                elif jump[5:6] == "-":
                    valid_coins.append("-" + jump[6:] + "\n")
                    # count += 1
            elif "jump" == jump[0:4]:
                if jump[5:6] == "+":
                    new_num = int(jump[6:])
                    new_jump = game_list[(i + num) + new_num]
                elif jump[5:6] == "-":
                    new_num = int(jump[6:])
                    new_num = -new_num
                    new_jump = game_list[(i + num) + new_num]
                if "coin" == new_jump[0:4]:
                    count += 1
                    if new_jump[5:6] == "+":
                        valid_coins.append(new_jump[6:] + "\n")
                        # count += 1
                    elif new_jump[5:6] == "-":
                        valid_coins.append("-" + new_jump[6:] + "\n")
                        # count += 1
                elif "jump" == new_jump[0:4]:
                    if new_jump[5:6] == "+":
                        new_num2 = int(new_jump[6:])
                        new_jump2 = game_list[(i + num) + new_num + new_num2]
                    elif new_jump[5:6] == "-":
                        new_num2 = int(new_jump[6:])
                        new_num2 = -new_num2
                        new_jump2 = game_list[(i + num) + new_num + new_num2]
                    if "coin" == new_jump2[0:4]:
                        count += 1
                        if new_jump2[5:6] == "+":
                            valid_coins.append(new_jump2[6:] + "\n")
                        # count += 1
                        elif new_jump2[5:6] == "-":
                            valid_coins.append("-" + new_jump2[6:] + "\n")
                    # count += 1
        elif "none" == current[0:4]:
            continue

    for i in range(len(valid_coins)):
        if valid_coins[i] == valid_coins[-1]:  # if last entry
            coins.write(valid_coins[i][:-1])  # removes preceding newline
        else:
            coins.write(valid_coins[i])
    coins.close()
    return coins, count


file, count = counting_coins("game.txt")
print(f"Total coins collected: {count}")
```

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: If you want to turn a file into a list of lines, use `game_list= cc.readlines()`

Comment: Use `current.startswith("coin")` instead of slicing.

Comment: You don't need to test for `+` and `-`. Just use `num = int(current[6:])`. If it begins with `-`, the `int()` function will return a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use all those nested `if` statements for jumping. Just reset the current index of the main loop to the element that you're jumping to.

You'll need to use a `while` loop instead of looping over `range()` so you can reset the index.

Instead of all that slicing, use `split()` to split each line into a command and argument.

```
i = 0
while i < len(game_list):
    current = game_list[i].split()
    if current[0] == "coin":
        count += 1
        valid_coins.append(current[1])
    elif current[0] == "jump"
        i += int(current[1])
    elif current[0] = "none":
        pass
    else:
        print(f"invalid line {game_list[i]}")

with open("coins.txt", "w") as coins:
    coins.write("\n".join(valid_coins))
```

There's no need for the `try/except`. Opening in `w` mode will create the file if it doesn't already exist, you don't need `x` for that.

Comment: Please read [answer]. Questions like this are clearly too broad and improperly specified; we are told that the code "has some bugs" but only one is even described, and then there is also a request for simplification (this is not [codereview.se]).